# Graphic input saved as vector

Tags: r, user-interface, input

I would like to have a graphical user input that is stored in a vector. The `menu` function accepts graphical input. See here:

```
choice <- menu(as.character(1:5), graphics= TRUE)
```

However, I want to type in any number rather than to choose a number from a vector. `readline()` accepts any input but it is shown in the `concole` and not in a separate window. What would be an easy way to do this? I want to avoid `shiny` since this doesn't seem an easy solution to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `svDialogs` to do this:

```
library(svDialogs)
user.input <- as.numeric(dlgInput("Enter a number")$res)
```